# Creating a placeholder having a shape that is a function of another shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder

Suppose that we have a tensorflow placeholder as follows:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (2, 2, 3 ..., 1))
```

I would like to create another tensor `y` whose shape is the as `x` except the first and second dimensions, which are three times those of `x`.

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (6, 6, 3, ..., 1))
```

The shape of `x` is not predefined, so what I want to do is something like the following:

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (x.shape[0]* 3, x.shape[1] * 3, remaining_are_the_same_as_x_shape))
```

Could you advice me how to do this in tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this ?

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (2, 2, 3 , 1))

shape = x.get_shape().as_list()
shape[0] = shape[0] * 3
shape[1] = shape[1] * 3

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=shape)
shape = y.get_shape().as_list()
print(shape)
```

> [6, 6, 3, 1]